# OQL to find instances implementing java.security.Principal

Tags: java, netbeans, visualvm, heap-dump, oql

This doesn't seem to return any result from Netbeans (which has the same heap analysis tools as VisualVM):

```
select x.name from java.security.Principal x
```

The query works if I put the name of a concrete class implementing Principal, but I'd need all implementations.

Tried the same in Eclipse Memory Analyzer, same results.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Heap dump does not have the information which classes implement particular interface. The only information available in the heap dump is about superclass. NetBeans Profiler can overcame this shortcoming - if you take a heap dump, while profiling or monitoring NetBeans project, it can compute the classes implementing particular interface from the project.

Comment: Thanks. So, how to ask Netbeans for this?

Comment: Just open your project in NetBeans and invoke Profile Project. You can use just Monitoring mode and once your application is started, take a heap dump.

Comment: Ok, missed the "Profiler" word in your solution. Well, no, those are production heap dumps and I can't profile those servers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[JHAT OQL 'instanceof' operator does not work with interface types](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6543691) BUG closed as **Won't fix** because *current heap dump format have no such info*. There are:

> BT2:WORK AROUND
>
> Manually find all implementing classes available in the heap snapshot (e.g. by searching through JAR
> files). Besides the difficulty and unreliability of finding all the possible impl classes, the
> result will not be very satisfactory because you are forced to either
>
> 1. Run a separate OQL query for each implementing class, making it hard to see all results in one
>    place.
>
> or
>
> 2. Use 'from Object o' and filter the results by checking the type, which is likely to be
>    prohibitively slow since it would traverse every object in the heap.

If you have some guess about class names or packages you may use query like this to find appropriate candidates:

```
filter(heap.classes(), "/org\\.hibernate\\.cfg\\.naming/(it.name)")
```

You can save search result via:

```
x = toArray(filter(..., ...))
```

and then query detail info without waiting for original query:

```
map(x, "{cl: it, sub: it.subclasses(), sup: it.superclasses()}")
```